# Bubbles Chart in asp.net is not working

Tags: asp.net, bubble-chart

I have Developed a Bubble Chart in Asp.net using a simple sqldatsource by defining x and y axis columns formaly.Now Problem is that the size of bubbles are same for all vlaues.For example the size of bubble for with 100 is same as the size of bubble for 2000 .Please any one tell me if there exist any property or attribute to check the size of bubbles according to the values.I have tried Much to find any property like this but all in vain.Kindly Help me

**Update**

```
 <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            Width="1115px" Height="556px" Compression="5">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Date" YValueMembers="Amount" 
                    ChartType="Bubble" YValuesPerPoint="2" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" 
                    IsXValueIndexed="True" MarkerSize="0" MarkerStyle="Circle" Palette="EarthTones">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringSMLAPP %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringSMLAPP.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT to_char(DS_DATE,'DD MON YYYY') &quot;Date&quot;, DS_AMT &quot;Amount&quot;FROM DIESEL where ds_amt &lt; 5000 and DS_DATE in('1-APR-2011','1-DEC-2011') order by 1">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provide any details how are you initializing series it's hard to give specific answer, but in general chart series has property `YValuesPerPoint` which should be set to 2 and to the methods `series.Points.DataBindXY()` or `series.Points.AddXY()` you can provide multiple Y values. First Y value provided would be responsible for place of bubble on Y axis and second Y value would be for bubble size.

So, to have one bubble in each series you can use following piece of code:

```
Chart chart = new Chart();
DataTable dt = GetData(); //your method to initialize data table with columns "Series", "X_value", "Y_value" and "BubbleSize_value"

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string seriesName = row["Series"].ToString();
    var series = new Series(seriesName);
    series.YValuesPerPoint = 2;
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble;
    series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;

    series.Points.AddXY(row["X_value"], row["Y_value"], row["BubbleSize_value"]);
    chart.Series.Add(series);
}
```

Comment: Sir I Have Updated My Current Code Please Tell me Now what is the Issue in mY code and Where i Have to change Now

Comment: If you are going to use `Amount` for both Y value and bubble size, just replace `YValueMembers="Amount"` by `YValueMembers="Amount,Amount"`. If you want to use another value for bubble size, let's name it `Size`, you need to add it to your SqlDataSource as well, so `"SELECT DISTINCT Size, to_char(DS_DATE,'DD MON YYYY') &quot;Date&quot;, DS_AMT &quot;Amount&quot; ...` and update `YValueMembers` like `YValueMembers="Amount,Size"`